# Add description to your own tag

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

I have just created a new tag. However, I'm not allowed to edit the tag description, it will need to be peer reviewed.

**If I have the permission to create a tag, wouldn't it make sense to also have permission to create the tag's description?**

This way, there will be less tags without description and less reviewing for moderators.

---

### Edit

Shouldn't it even be mandatory to include a description when creating a tag?

Comment: While I understand your reasoning and desire for efficiency, I can't help but ask: why is having your description reviewed a problem? After all, if you haven't done it before on health SE, wouldn't you like someone more experienced to verify if you are going in the right direction?

Comment: @Lucky I actually haven't thought of that. Mainly I was worried because moderators seem to have quite a lot to do...

Comment: All users that have passed a certain rep threshold (I think it's 1500 if I read the help centre page correctly) can review tag wiki edits, it should pop-up under "suggested edits" reviews once you create it. Similarly to other reviews (edits by users below 1000 rep, closing questions etc.) it requires a certain amount of community votes to be approved. We don't have too many high-rep users, but I still think voting on an edit will be resolved more quickly than changing a policy all across SE (although I support your initiative) :-). We are a slow-developing beta, arm yourself with patience ;-)

Comment: Yeah, that threshold is 1500. There are not many high-rep users indeed....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might make more sense, but that is not something that we control on a site to site basis. That is an overall stack exchange policy, you would need to look on meta to see if there is a reason for it, or if it warrants discussion for changing how that is handled.

Comment: I just created [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292659/adding-tag-description) on meta, following your guidance. Good idea!